# How to Count inversions in multi dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given a 1-D array say with 4 elements 5 4 2 3,i know of the modified merge sort(divide and conquer) algorithm to count the no of inversions(pairs such that i < j and A[i] > A[j].
But if i am given a square 2-D array(N * N),how to count inversions in something better than O(N^4) ?
Note that in 2-D arrays inversions are defined as pairs such that
for 2 elements having co-ordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

```
x1 <= x2,
y1 <= y2,
and A[x2][y2] < A[x1][y1].
Say for N = 2
5 4
2 3
```

the no of inversions will be 4.
pairs (5,4) (5,2) (5,3) and (4,3)

I am new to stack overflow.please forgive for formatting problems.

Answer (score 1):

### Inversion Count Using Binary Indexed Tree / Fenwick Tree

[Fenwick Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) is very useful data-structure for maintaining frequencies for each data element and manipulating cumulative frequencies data table.

This tutorial - [BIT](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/) - will give you great start with the data structure. It has all the implementation details.

---

Having understood the data structure, you can use it to count inversions in array. Suppose we have `a[1...n]` and inversion is defined as all pairs `i, j` such that `i<j => a[i] > a[j]`

Initially, all the frequencies are initialized to 0.

```
for i = n to 1
    res += range-sum(1, a[i]-1)
    insert(a[i])
```

Finally, res will be your answer.

Time taken: O(nlogn)

---

For multi-dimensional, create multi-dimensional binary indexed tree. The above tutorial gives an example of [2D-BIT](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/#2d)

Here is my implementation as per above tutorial:

```
#define sz(x) ((int)x.size())
#define LSOne(x) (x & -x)
typedef long long LL;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vvi;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;

//Use one based indexing
class FenwickTree{
public:
  vvi ft;
  int n;
  FenwickTree(int _n){
    n=_n;
    ft.assign(n,vi(n,0));
  }
  int rsq(int x,int y){
    int sum=0;
    for(;x;x-=LSOne(x))sum += rsqY(x,y);
    return sum;
  }
  int rsqY(int x,int y){
    int sum=0;
    for(;y;y-=LSOne(y))sum += ft[x][y];
    return sum;
  }
  int rsq(int _x,int _y,int x,int y){
    return rsq(x,y)-rsq(x,_y-1)-rsq(_x-1,y)+rsq(_x-1,_y-1);
  }
  void update(int x,int y,int v){
    for(;x<=n;x+=LSOne(x))updateY(x,y,v);
  }
  void updateY(int x,int y,int v){
    for(;y<=n;y+=LSOne(y))ft[x][y] += v; 
  }
  void clear(){
    ft.assign(n,vi(n,0));
  }
};
```